# Exhibit a subset of $\mathbb A^2$ which is constructible, but not locally closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples

A subset of a variety is **locally closed** if it is the intersection of a closed subset with an open subset; it is **constructible** if it is a finite union of locally closed subsets.

Suppose that the base field is algebraically closed.

> Exhibit a subset of $\mathbb A^2$ which is constructible, but not locally closed.

Would you please show me the way of finding such a subset and proving that it satisfies the condition?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you seen this post http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45667/20998?

Comment: Are you working over an algebraically closed field?

Comment: @azarel: Thanks very much for the comment. But the question you referred to considers about the common topology, while I am thinking in Zariski topology. For example, the example given by Matt E in that question is the union of the open subset $\mathbb{A}^2 - \{ (x,y) | x =0 \} $ with the closed subset $ \{ (0,0) \}$.

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks very much for reminding me of this. I forgot to write in the question that the base field was algebraically closed.

Comment: Dear ShinyaSakai, My answer that @azarel links works either in the Zariski topology (which is what I had in mind when I wrote it) or the usual topology if the ground field is the complex numbers.   In particular, it answers your question.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt E: Thanks very much. I thought that in a wrong way... Regards,